# uploading and downloading storage images in firebase with VueJs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, firebase-storage

im building this simple application using Vue/vuex and firebase where i want to facilitate  users upload images and once the app gets updated those images get reached from firebase  storage , modifying the current database with the new uploaded image
Here is my code:

```
createMeet({ commit, getters }, payload) {
      const newMeet = {
        title: payload.title,
        description: payload.description,
        location: payload.location,
        date: payload.date,
        video_url: payload.video_url,
        idCreator: getters.getUser.id
      }
      let image_url;
      let key;
      firebase.database().ref('meetUps').push(newMeet)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data)
          key = data.key
          return key
        })
        .then(key => {
          const filename = payload.image.name
          const fileExtension = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
          return firebase.storage().ref('meetUps/' + key + '.' + fileExtension).put(payload.image)
        })---the image get storaged in the firebase storage

        .then(fileData => {
          image_url = fileData.metadata.downloadURLs()
          return firebase.database().ref('meetUps/').child(key).update({ image_url: image_url })
        })--------->updating in the database the storaged object in there passing a new paranmeter
                    image_url, with a new value contained in variable iimage_url
        .then(() => {
          commit('meetsCreator', {
            ...newMeet,
            image_url: image_url,------------>putting changes in some mutation which modifies the state
            id: key,

          })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
      // commit('meetsCreator',newMeet)
    },
```

the images get push to the firebase storaged but once i try to modify the database adding this new element (image) using downloadUrls, doesnt work. 
Any advice please?....thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#get-downloadurl) method from the JavaScript SDK, which is asynchronous and returns a Promise that resolves with the download URL.

So, the following should do the trick:

```
  //...
  firebase.database().ref('meetUps').push(newMeet)
    .then(ref => {
      key = ref.key
      const filename = payload.image.name
      const fileExtension = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
      return firebase.storage().ref('meetUps/' + key + '.' + fileExtension).put(payload.image)
    })
    .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
       return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    .then(url => {
      return firebase.database().ref('meetUps/').child(key).update({ image_url: url })
    })
    //....
```

Comment: really thanks Renaud , simple and fast....really thanks for your great help!!!!